# Place an UIImageView behind the tableView in a UITableViewController Subclass

Tags: uitableview, background, uiimageview

I am trying to place a UIImageView behind a the tableView in a view controller that is a subclass of UITableViewController.  I have gotten the following code to sort of work, but the image scrolls with the rows in the table.

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[backgroundView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"woodbackground1"]];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView];
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

I tried the suggestions in this post
[Add UIView behind UITableView in UITableViewController code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079002/add-uiview-behind-uitableview-in-uitableviewcontroller-code) but they produce the same result, am image that across with the table.

Is there a way to place the image view behind the tableview so that the image does not move with the table?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

Why not use

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
```

Comment: Doing so does not allow the image to scroll along with the view. So this should be what the asker wants. But just a caveat.

Comment: Odd. I've tried adding this in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear.  Is it also required to set the table and the cell's alphas to < 1?